# Why does python3.7 pass argv elements alongside 'garbage'

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, arguments

I had this script working for me, before I decided I'm gonna rewrite everything and make it portable. 
Without delving too much into the details, there's a central Bash script, which calls 5 other Bash scripts in their own respective folders. I have no intention of porting to Windows anytime soon, as of current this is just for Linux.

The execution path of the central Bash script is:

```
dos.1/1-init.sh dos.1/

dos.2/1-trace-to-file.sh dos.2/ dos.1/

dos.3/1-recognize-categories.sh dos.3/

dos.4/1-ping-in-groups.sh dos.4/ dos.3/

dos.5/init.sh dos.5/ dos.4/
```

I run with `./init.sh`

Before the script was 'portable' I was using explicit file paths inside each respective script. All was well and good. The program itself is a combination of Bash and Python, and writes to files in one directory, so that they can be manipulated in various ways, before being read back into different parts of the program.

I understand that the fastest way to do this would be to write a monolithic Python script, using subprocess calls for the Bash side of things... However, I am doing it this way to ease maintenance, and (before I started making it 'portable') it was lightning fast.

My issue now is this: each time I have to read text into Python (either from SQL or from file) there's always this added garbage. Up until this point, I have been using sed, awk and Python's `.rstrip()` function to manage this... Which is all well and good, but this one damn function will not play nice... And I feel there must be a better way.

In bash I call it with:

```
$prog_dir=$1
$data_dir=$2
$prog_dir/2fast-ping.py $data_dir/group0.txt > $prog_dir/group0_averages.txt
$prog_dir/2fast-ping.py $data_dir/group1.txt > $prog_dir/group1_averages.txt
...
```

Now I know that I could write to file from within Python, but in this instance I have other reasons not to.

The issue, is that when the 2fast-ping.py script is ran, it reads the text file in with commas and a newline char. I have vigorously checked and I can confirm that the `group#.txt` files 100% do not contain commas. Here's the Python:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import select
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

filename = sys.argv[1]

f = open(filename, "r")
ips = [elem.rstrip('\n') for elem in f]
print(ips)
f.close()
```

The script goes on to do some work on the IPs afterwards, but this is the painful part. If I call the script direct from CLI:  `./2fast-ping.py ../dos.3/group0.txt`, the text is processed PROPERLY and the superseding instructions actually function. But, when called from the first init script, the program basically sh*ts itself because each line is read in with commas. It works until the point where it starts to use the processed info, then:

```
<actual IP would be here>
ping: ('##.###.###.###',): Name or service not known
```

Of course, the issue is the ('',)  But, Python is adding that in, and I don't know how to stop it :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but what you showed here: `('##.###.###.###',)` looks very much like a string representation of a one-element tuple. Make sure you pass a single string rather than a tuple to your 2fast-ping.py.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. My next question would then be: how would I go about reading an text file in as individual strings as opposed to tuples? I'm going to try using a while loop with readline() statements and get back to you if that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, so reading into an array with a context manager didn't seem to work either :/ But again, even when using the with open(filename) as f, I can call the script direct from the CLI, but not from the central bash script.

Comment: Are your files (group0.txt etc. ) static or created dynamically by the init script? Also: how exactly do you call ping in your code (seems you have omitted this part)?

Comment: They're static at the the time of interpretation. I'm calling ping as a bash script using a subprocess call to a custom ping command, however it's called using the ThreadPoolExecutor so as to speed up the process. The actual bash ping script looks like this:

Comment: ping -n -i 0.2 -c 3 $1|tail -1| awk '{print $4}'|cut -f 2 -d'/'

Comment: And $1 is…? I assume there is another shell script containing the above command, how do you call that script?

Comment: Sorry, very ambiguous on my behalf:

This is the ping function, which calls the bash script

`def _ping(ip):
    a = ip.rstrip()
    b = subprocess.Popen(['/dos.4/b-shell-ping.sh',\
     ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    c = b.stdout.readline()
    print(f'{a} = {c}')
`
This function 100% works. I then run this function using ThreadPoolExecutor, like so:

`with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=64) as executor:
    results = executor.map(_ping, ips)
    executor.shutdown(wait=True)
Whereby ips is what I ascertained from argv[1]
`

Comment: Okay, so, my bad entirely. I've resolved the issue. It wasn't anything to do with the Python, the initial bash init was passing the folder names with a superseding /

All si good

Answer (score 0):

Python code was okay, just passing an additional / with the argument :(